# IE11 style.maxHeight not set from css

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

**Objective**: Add a scroll bar when internal content exceeds maximum height, otherwise set to hidden overflow (as scroll bar shows up if setting `overflow-y: scroll`)

**Context**: This is in a win8.1 app (so ie11 trident)

**Problem**: the `style.maxHeight` on the `#table-wrapper` div is set to `''`

My **css**

```
#threads table {
    width: 100%;
}
#table-wrapper {
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

My **Js**

```
var threadTable = document.getElementById('thread-table');
var tableWrapper = document.getElementById('table-wrapper');


if (threadTable.clientHeight > tableWrapper.style.maxHeight) {
    tableWrapper.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
} else {
    tableWrapper.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}
```

My **html**

```
<div id="threads" class="info">
  <h3>IE Build Info</h3>
  <div id="table-wrapper">
    <table id="thread-table"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Suggestions would be helpful. There is probably a better way to do what I'm doing, but I don't want a scroll bar (even if it disappears after a while) to be there when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: The `.style` object only shows CSS properties set directly on the element.

Comment: I was reading around on SO before I posted and someone said `style.height` should be set if the css height was set? were they wrong?

Comment: Yes, they were wrong.

Comment: Is there no way to learn the css style applied to an object unless it was set in JS itself?

Comment: Search for `getComputedStyle()`

Comment: Throw an answer down there and get your reward, if you care. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing just a vertical scroll it is very simple. Here is the markup I use:

```
<div class="y-scroller-wrapper movie-showtimes-scroller">
    <div class="movie-showtimes-wrapper">
       <!-- Items go here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The y-scroller wrapper is the container where the overflow is set. The width has to be the 100%, the height is also 100% of its container. So this needs to be inside something with set dimensions. A lot of times in my modern layouts the main element is absolutely positioned so I can do a fluid layout.

This is the CSS:

```
.x-scroller-wrapper, .xy-scroller-wrapper, .y-scroller-wrapper {
-webkit-overflow-style: none;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
-moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow-scrolling: touch;
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
overflow-style: none;
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
-ms-scroll-snap-type: proximity;
-ms-scroll-translation: vertical-to-horizontal;
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
padding-right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

.x-scroller-wrapper {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
    touch-action: pan-x;
}

.y-scroller-wrapper {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

I have a sort of working demo up right now, you will need to reduce the browser width to < 600 pixels for the vertical scroll. If it is wider it adjust to a horizontal scroll. It looks like there is a bug where it is not resizing properly if you manually shrink so just refresh at small width if it does not reset. http://pentonmovies.love2dev.com/

If you are curious the vertical to horizontal is managed through media queries for a responsive effect. I need to change from the resize event to a media query listener to make it better right now ;)

Also IE has some great touch and native scroll support the other platforms do not have at this time. I hope this helps you out.